# Excel VBA Reading XML Errors (Blank attributes?)

Tags: excel, vba

I have some code (subroutine macro) that's meant to search through a list of US state, get their name and abbreviation and then search a sheet for that state to get a corresponding integer value.The code largely works, but at the end of the loop through the results, there is *always* a blank result (even if I check for it, which I've done in a variety of different ways). This seems to be the cause of errors if I try to apply a function to the result.

```
Dim xmlDoc As DOMDocument30
Set xmlDoc = New DOMDocument30
xmlDoc.Load ("C:\xampp\htdocs\election\states.xml")

Dim list As IXMLDOMNodeList
Set list = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//states/state")

Dim abbrNode As IXMLDOMAttribute
Dim abbr As String
Dim stateNode As IXMLDOMAttribute
Dim state As String
Dim resultNode As IXMLDOMAttribute
Dim result As String
Dim node As IXMLDOMNode
Dim childNode As IXMLDOMNode
Dim NumberOfVotes As Integer

For Each node In list
    Set abbrNode = node.Attributes.getNamedItem("abbreviation")
    Set stateNode = node.Attributes.getNamedItem("name")
    Set resultNode = node.Attributes.getNamedItem("result")

If (Trim(abbrNode.Text) <> "") Then
    MsgBox stateNode.Text
End If
```

Even with the check for an empty string (also checked for if abbrNode was nothing), I always get an empty MsgBox at the end, when I'd rather it end at Wyoming.

If I run the lookup function in the loop:

```
Set NumberOfVotes = lookupElectoralVotes(stateNode.Text)
```

I get a compile error (object required), I assume because it can't perform that function on a blank result.

I also get an error if I try to set a variable to equal stateNode.Text or similar:

```
Set state = stateNode.Text
```

Also generates a compile error, I'm not sure why, but again possibly due to the final result being blank. But I can use stateNode.Text by itself so maybe I'm just missing a core concept of VBA.

The XML file is nothing complex:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<states>
    <state name="ALABAMA" abbreviation="AL" result="U"/>
    <state name="ALASKA" abbreviation="AK" result="U"/>
    <state name="ARIZONA" abbreviation="AZ" result="U"/>
</states>
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: you SET a reference to an object, not a string as in the case of  _Set state = stateNode.Text_ - so irrespective of whether is nothing, would still error as not an object on the rhs

Comment: What is _lookupElectoralVotes_ ? There is no definition with this in the signature above. How big is the file? Can you pastebin.com a link and put the full file there? .

Comment: Thanks, I misunderstood what Set was for, so that solves the compile issues, which I thought were secondary.

Comment: But still would like to not get the blank result (or at least filter it out).

getElectoralVotes() is a dummy function at the moment, just returns an integer. The same "Set" problem, not an issue now!

Comment: Have you checked what debug.print xmldoc.xml  returns?